# If a boat can travel at 10 mph in a river with no current, will it always be moving 10 mph compared to the water at full speed, regardless of current?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, relative-motion, textbook-erratum

I must be confused, because it seems to me that the boat would always be traveling 10 mph in relation to the water regardless of the water's velocity, but the answer key for my assignment states the boat is traveling 15 mph compared to the water when the boat it going full speed North and the water is going 5mph South. Why is this the case?

Comment: Buy a new book. This is such a fundamental conceptual error (not even a math error, which would be okay) that I doubt the rest of the book has any value.

Comment: Is the assignment formulation available from an online source?

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct.

Your book is wrong.

That simple...

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the air always remains stationary, then no.
The "top speed" of the boat is affected by both water resistance AND air resistance since part of it cuts through water while the remaining part cuts through air.

But the underlying principle of what you are saying is correct. The water current essentially adds to the thrust of the boat, thus altering the "top speed"

Calculating the actual "top speed" of the boat, given water speed and wind speed is very complex, since water and air offer different amounts of resistance, and you don't know how hydrodynamic or aerodynamic the boat is. I mean, think about it... suppose the boat happened to be a sailing boat; in that case it was intentionally engineered to catch wind and slice through water.

So basically, you AND the book are BOTH wrong.
In the real world, you have no idea what speed the boat would go given the precise weather conditions.

Comment: So, if you shut off the engine, the boat will move through the water at the current speed?

Comment: Not if the current speed is faster than the wind speed.